# SQL multiple table Syntax

Tags: sql

I have a table with a bunch of specific details and some detail codes for bridges. There are other separate tables with the descriptions for the various codes.  For instance a table for Curb type, table for sidewalk type, another for joint type and so on.
I would like to create a query that gives me all the details per Bridge, but with the Code descriptions from the other tables for the fields that supply the code.  the result would give me the ID, dimensions, curb code description, Sidewalk code description and so on.
 Any help to point me in the right direction is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: you probably want an INNER JOIN. You can easily research the correct syntax and examples etc online. Or if you've taken a simple SQL tutorial it should have introduced the concept pretty early on. It's one of the more basic things you can do. Have you done any research/learning yourself yet? Try to find tutorials/examples for your database product specifically (you didn't say which DBMS product you're working with), although a simple join should be pretty much identical across all the major vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT b.Id, b.something, b.CurbTypeID, c.CurbDescription, b.SidewalkTypeID, s.SidewalkDescription
FROM Bridges b
INNER JOIN Curb c on c.CurbID = b.CurbTypeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sidewalk s on s.SidewalkID = b.SidewalkTypeID
```

The difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN being that you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you're not confident that all your SidewalkTypeID values are actually listed in the Sidewalk table, or if SidewalkTypeID  is blank sometimes.

Comment: How would I get results for bridge table left curb type = 1, bridge table Right curb = 2?  The Left Outer Join just leaves the description blank because they aren't equal.

Comment: I got it by setting up tables in Access and playing with them the SQL is: SELECT BridgeDetails.BIN, Curb_Type.[CODE DESCRIPTION] AS [left Curb Type], Curb_Type_1.[CODE DESCRIPTION] As [Right Curb Type]
FROM (BridgeDetails LEFT JOIN Curb_Type ON BridgeDetails.[CURB TYPE LEFT] = Curb_Type.CODE) LEFT OUTER JOIN Curb_Type AS Curb_Type_1 ON BridgeDetails.[CURB TYPE RIGHT] = Curb_Type_1.[CODE];

Comment: I should've mentioned I added the curb type table twice, once with an alias